# Iphone 3d games using Open Gl Es

Tags: iphone, xcode, opengl-es

I want to make 3d games for the iphone and with all this doubt about Unity and Apples new sdk agreement I'm wondering what the best way forward is?

A lot of people recommend opengl es and point me in the direction of the open gl es bible and likewise, the problem is none of this actually talk about setting a game up i.e loading a character, scene , AI etc.

Yet a lot of people are using Open GL es please could someone help me out, I really feel like I'm missing out on something.

Are there any good tutorials/books that cover this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Oolong Engine was written and is maintained by professional game developers.  It should get you started on some concepts, but programming a game from the nuts and bolts is a big step from using Unity.  Good luck.

http://code.google.com/p/oolongengine/